# Determine How Much Space Each Site is Using - Windows Sharepoint Services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

Our content database for WSS is growing out of control.  I'd like to be able to do some reporting that will show which sites are using the most space, as well as what documents or document libraries are using the most storage space. These types of features doesn't appear to be built into Windows Sharepoint Services so I'll need a tool or some way to query for this information.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of getting the information, one of the easiest is most probably via this tool:  **SharePoint Space Monitor**

(the link I had is now dead, but you can still find the software online)

Comment: Link in answer is dead.